# Java memory visibility outside the synchronized lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, memory-barriers, memory-visibility

Does the synchronized lock guarantee the following code always print 'END'?

```
public class Visibility {

    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread thread_1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i);
                while (true) {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.println("END");
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (Visibility.class){}
                }
            }
        });
        thread_1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        synchronized (Visibility.class) {
            i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I run it on my laptop, it always print 'END', but I am wondering is it be guaranteed by the JVM that this code will always print 'END'?

Further, If we add one line inside the empty `synchronized` block, and it becomes to:

```
public class Visibility {

    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread thread_1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i);
                while (true) {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.println("END");
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (Visibility.class){
                        int x = i; // Added this line.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread_1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        synchronized (Visibility.class) {
            i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now is it be guaranteed by the JVM that this code will always print 'END'?

Comment: Why an empty `synchronized` block?

Comment: @MauricePerry If without the empty synchronized block, the code will always run and never exits.

Comment: It seams your goal is to protect `i`. so I you should put the test inside the `synchronized` block.

Comment: @MauricePerry I want to know why the empty `synchronized ` make the code exits?

Comment: The `synchronized` block in addition to ensuring mutual exclusions, also ensures that the processor cache is flushed so that changes in the cache are seen by other cores/processors.

Comment: AFAIK it's a side-effect and not guaranteed. If `i` is not declared `volatile` then there is no guarantee that the observed value of `i` inside the loop ever changes. There are many situations where (with the current OpenJDK implementation) it *will* become visible, but those aren't guaranteed by the spec.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That's also what I thought, but I am not sure, so want to discuss about this.

Comment: I edited the question and added one further case.

Comment: There is nothing specific about the synchronization here that would ensure the text _"END"_ is printed.  You would need to synchronize the _i_ accessors, use an _[AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)_ object, or the _[volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)_ modifier.

Comment: @Reilas What about the latter 'added one line' version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [JLS §17.4.5: Happens-before order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

In other words, HB (Happens-before) is transitive. And HB is the primary player in observability: It is not possible to observe state in line Y as it was before line X executed if `hb(x, y)` - and that's exactly what you are trying to do (or rather, prevent from happening): You are interested in whether line Y (`if (i == 1)`) can observe state as it was prior to line X (`i = 1`, in the synchronized block at the bottom of the snippet).

Given that transitivity rule, the answer for your specific snippet is 'yes' - you're guaranteed that it prints `END`. Always take care in extrapolating an analysis for one particular snippet to a more general case - this stuff doesn't simplify easily, you have to apply happens-before analysis every time (or, more usually, avoid interactions between threads by way of field writes as much as you can):

- `hb(exiting a synchronized block, entering it)` is a thing. different threads acquiring the monitor is an ordered affair, and there are HB relationships between these. Hence, there's an hb relationship between the second-to-last `}` (exiting the block) <sup>1</sup> and the zero-statements `synchronized` block in the thread.
- If the inner thread somehow runs afterwards (weird, as that would mean it has taken *more* than 1 second to even start, but technically a JVM makes no timing guarantees, so possible in theory), `i` is already 1. It's possible this change has not been 'synced' yet, except then the while loop hits that no-content `synchronized` block which then established hb, and thus forces visibility of `i` being `1`.
- If the inner thread runs before (100% of all cases, what with that `Thread.sleep(1000)` in there, pretty much), the same logic applies eventually.
- To actually add it together, we need to add the 'natural' hb rule: Bytecode X and Y establish `hb(x, y)` if X and Y are executed by the same thread and Y comes after X in program order. i.e. given: `y = 5; System.out.println(y)` you can't observe y being as it was before `y = 5;` ran - this is the 'duh!' HB rule - java would be rather useless as a language if the JVM can just reorder stuff in a single thread at will, of course. That + the transitivity rule is enough.

### One technical issue here

The thread you fire up never voluntarily relinquishes which can cause some havoc (nothing in that code will 'sleep' the CPU). You should **never** write code that just busy-spins like this, the JVM is not particularly clear about how things work then, and it'll cause massive heat/power issues on the CPU! On a single core processor, the JVM is essentially allowed to spend all its time on that busy-wait, **forever**, and this is the one way in which you can make a JVM not print `END`, ever: Because the main thread that sets `i` to 1 **never** gets around to it. This breaks the general point of threads. `synchronized` introduces a savepoint, so it'll eventually get pre-empted, but that can take quite a while. It can take far longer than a second on the right hardware.

Trivially fixed by shoving some sort of `sleep` or `wait` in that busy-loop, or using `j.u.concurrent` locks/semaphores/etc.

### But won't that empty `synchronized` block get optimized out?

No. The JLS dictates pretty much down to the byte exactly what `javac` **must** produce. It is not allowed to optimize empty loops. It's the hotspot engine (i.e. `java.exe` - the runtime) that does things like 'oh, this loop has no observable effects that I'm supposed to guarantee, therefore, I can optimize the whole thing away entirely', and the JMM 17.4.5 indicates it cannot do that. If a JVM impl 'optimizes it away', it'd be buggy.

We can confirm this with `javap`:

```
> cat Test.java
class Test {
  void test() {
    synchronized(this) {}
  }
}
> javac Test.java; javap -c -v Test
[ ... loads of output elided ...]
3: monitorenter
4: aload_1
5: monitorexit
```

`monitorenter` is bytecode for the opening brace in a `synchronized (x){}` block, and `monitorexit` is bytecode for the closing brace (or any other control flow out of one - exception throwing and `break` / `continue` / `return` also make `javac` emit `monitorexit` bytecode.

### Closing note

I assume the question was asked in the spirit of: Soo.. what happens here? Not in the spirit of: "Is this fine to write". It's **not** okay - other than the spinloop (never good), forcing the reader to go on a goose chase determining that HB is in fact set up to ensure this code does what you think it does, and requiring multiple details about the HB ruleset (the synchronized stuff *and* the transitivity rule *and* knowledge that empty sync blocks aren't optimized away) - not to mention an obvious bit of bizarro code (an empty sync block) which nevertheless does have a function here, none of that is particularly maintainable. The proper way to do this specific job is most likely to use a simple lock from `java.util.concurrent`, or at least to move the `synchronized` block to encompass all content in the `while` block. Also, locking on things code outside your direct control can acquire (and `Visibility.class` is, trivially, a global singleton) is a very bad idea: The only non-broken way to do that, is to extensively document your locking behaviour (and therefore, you're now signed up to maintain that behaviour indefinitely, or you're forced to release a major (i.e. backwards incompatible) version if you change it). Almost always you want to lock on things you control - i.e. `private final Object lock = new Object[0];` - an object that cannot possibly be referred to outside your direct control.

---

[1] Technically HB is a JVM affair and applies to bytecode. That closing brace, however, really does have a bytecode equivalent (most closing braces do not; that one does): It's the release of the monitor ('freeing' the `synchronized` lock). Which is exactly the bytecode that is HB relative to a later-ordered acquiring of that same lock object.

Comment: Great detailed answer as always. Only minor nit: I'd be a bit more explicit what "the answer is no" means, as that depends very much on the specific phrasing of the question and sometimes questions are unclear about which way around they phrase it (or use different phrasing throughout the question).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've qualified my `no` a little bit, you know, by changing it to a 'yes' - between eyeballs and brain neurons the question flipped into 'is this code problematic?', but the actual question is: "Is it guaranteed to print 'END'". Which it is, for this very specific code, the way I understand the JMM, yes, that is a guarantee. For an encore I've added an addendum that delves into whether the empty-ness of the `synchronized`  block is an issue. It isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers, just one more question, what if we add one line inside the empty `synchronized`, it becomes to: `synchronized (Visibility.class){ int x = i;}`, now is it be guaranteed by the JVM that it will always print 'END'?

Comment: @Anonemous I edited the answer in a rather crucial way - it was guaranteed to print END always. With 'no', I meant: "No, this code doesn't have JMM problems".